# Updating message template receipt to include all of the price fields selected in a price set

Tags: wordpress, tokens, message-templates

Our membership form uses a price set with 7 price fields - the "umbrella" membership and then optional extra memberships (sub-memberships for affiliated groups).

In the message template used for the automated receipt, `{ts}Membership Type{/ts}: {$membership_name}` is used to display the user's membership. At present, this displays the "umbrella membership" and does not include all of the price fields they have selected. The total amount is correct with the default code/tokens.

What token/s do I need to use to display all of the price fields (memberships) selected?

We're using WordPress 4.5 and CiviCRM 4.7.3

Comment: Didn't had a chance to look at Civi's 4.7 template but if you are using price fields/price set, shouldn't the `Membership Type` part be omitted and instead you would see the `Membership Fee` header and right afterwards the  LineItem with its label (Umbrella - something), fee, start dateand end date?